# How to send notifications at regular intervals between fixed timings from an app

Tags: android

**The aim:** To build an android app that sends out a notification to the user at a regular interval (say, every 10 minutes) between specific timings(say, between 5 pm to 8 pm)

**The Problem**: I don't know how to do this.

Although I have been learning about NotificationManager and NotificationCompat.Builder, I do require some help...

Comment: you need a back end to do this task you can only show notifications if you are in android.

Comment: you're not clear... can't understand